# Blocked UI Thread for withProgress coming from external library method

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions

I'm currently working on an extension that is pretty much complete, but I'm trying to add some visual indicators for a longer running task. My initial guess was that there is a missing async/await in my code, but I can't find the culprit. My progress indicator isn't showing up until after my code has completed and I have been able to track down the method that is blocking the UI thread (commenting this method out fixes everything). The culprit is a method coming from an external package I'm using.

Below is a trimmed down code snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
import { composeAndValidate } from "@apollo/federation";

vscode.window.withProgress(
{
    location: vscode.ProgressLocation.Notification,
    title: 'Composing',
    cancellable: false
},
async progress => {
    const sdls = await getSdls()

    //The call to composeAndValidate is blocking UI thread
    const results = composeAndValidate(sdls);

    ...some other code
})

//Somewhere else
async function getSdls(){
    ... async stuff
    return [{name: 'test', typeDefs: 'type Query { me: String }`}];
}
```

It seems I need to look at the `@apollo/federation` library a little deeper, but I don't see any Promises used in those method calls (although I haven't looked deeper at the `graphql-js` side of things).

Any ideas of how I can further investigate on unblocking the UI thread? It's not a problem for most of my use cases, but very large designs in my extension cause ~3s delay that doesn't prompt VS Code to kill the extension rather just confusing temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using `yield` in my solution. A tweak to the code example above is what I ended up using:

```
vscode.window.withProgress(
{
    location: vscode.ProgressLocation.Notification,
    title: 'Composing',
    cancellable: false
},
async progress => {
    const sdls = await getSdls()

    //The call to composeAndValidate is blocking UI thread
    const results = getCompositionResults(sdls).next().value;

    ...some other code
})

function* getCompositionResults(sdls){
    yield composeAndValidate(sdls);
}

//Somewhere else
async function getSdls(){
    ... async stuff
    return [{name: 'test', typeDefs: 'type Query { me: String }`}];
}
```

***Note***: *using `yield` typically means you have to convert lots of sync things to async, [so read up on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*), but for my case it worked out.*

yields aren’t 100% trivial, they mean you have to convert lots of sync things to async and make sure you’re not relying anywhere on the assumption that “code is sync therefore no other code is modifying data structures that it touches